# Has the behavior of asymmetric transitions changed in SwiftUI 4 / iOS 16?

Tags: ios, swiftui, transition, observableobject, ios-animations

I've been using an asymmetric transition which has been working flawlessly during the time of iOS 15. However, with the introduction of iOS 16 the transition no longer works as expected.

In short: In my app I'm using a paged tabview. When you swipe pages I want to insert/remove another view with an animation/transition, matching the page swipe direction.

Since it's much easier to describe the problem in code I've created an isolated case where my problem is repeatable, so you can see it for yourself.

```
import SwiftUI

class SharedStore: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var selectedPage: Int = 0 {
        willSet {
            if newValue > selectedPage  {

                self.pageDirection = .forward
                
            } else {
                
                self.pageDirection = .reverse
            }
        }
    }
    
    var pageDirection: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection = .forward
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var sharedStore = SharedStore()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("Page \(sharedStore.selectedPage)")
                .id(sharedStore.selectedPage)
                .frame(maxWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                .animation(.easeInOut, value: sharedStore.selectedPage)
                .transition(
                    .asymmetric(
                        insertion: .move(edge: sharedStore.pageDirection == .forward ? .trailing : .leading),
                        removal: .move(edge: sharedStore.pageDirection == .forward ? .leading : .trailing)
                    )
                )

            TabView(selection: $sharedStore.selectedPage) {
                ForEach(0..<10, id:\.self) { index in
                    Text("Hello \(index)")
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Run the above on a iOS 16 simulator. Swipe a couple of pages and then change direction. Notice that the transition of the top view gets weird. The view is removed and inserted from the same edge.

If you however run the same code on a iOS 15 simulator, you will see that the top view animation matches the page swipe direction nicely, even when you change direction.

My assumption is that something has changed with the asymmetric transitions in SwiftUI 4 / iOS 16, hence the title of the question. Or could it be something the published property and the willSet observer?

Note that I'm far from a professional iOS developer, so I'm also considering that this actually worked in iOS 15 by pure luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right and transition edges *sometimes* behave differently in iOS 16, at least on removal. For cases where it is not working consistently, you can solve by using a `ViewModifier` to apply the move transition in a way dependent on iOS version. Here are two examples:

```swift
/// View modifier that applies a move transition on the leading edge
struct TransitionLeading: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            content.transition(.move(edge: .leading))
        } else {
            content.transition(
                .asymmetric(
                    insertion: .move(edge: .leading),
                    removal: .move(edge: .trailing)
                )
            )
        }
    }
}

/// View modifier that applies a move transition on the trailing edge
struct TransitionTrailing: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            content.transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
        } else {
            content.transition(
                .asymmetric(
                    insertion: .move(edge: .trailing),
                    removal: .move(edge: .leading)
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

My answer to [SwiftUI bi-directional move transition moving the wrong way in certain cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75806791) shows these modifiers being used.