# Buggy transition animation of a view. Is this a bug on iOS 16?

Tags: swiftui

I have this code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var redVisible = false
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Color.blue

      if redVisible {
        RedView($redVisible)
      }
    }
    .customTransitions()
    .onAppear{
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 2) {
        withAnimation {
          redVisible = true
        }
      }
    }
    
    .padding()
  }
}

struct RedView: View {
  @Binding var isVisible: Bool

  init(_ isVisible:Binding<Bool>) {
    self._isVisible = isVisible
  }
    var body: some View {
      ZStack {
        Color.red
      }
      .customTransitions()
      .onAppear {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 2) {
          withAnimation {
            isVisible = false
          }
        }
      }
    }
}

struct CustomTransitions: ViewModifier {
  
  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
      .transition(returnTransition())
    
  }
  
  func returnTransition() -> AnyTransition {
    return .asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge:.leading),
                       removal: .move(edge:.trailing))
  }
  
}

extension View {
  func customTransitions() -> some View {
    self.modifier(CustomTransitions())
  }
}
```

The result:

[image]

What I am trying to do is:

1. View blue shows.
2. Two seconds later, the red view moves from the right to the left, but it is moving the other way around or the documentation is misleading.
3. Two seconds after that, the red view exits by moving the reverse, that is from from the left to the right.

I need the same movement as when you tap a cell on a table to see the detail view and back from the detail view to the table.

Notice that the last animation doesn't show at all. It is crap.

What is wrong?

Comment: you can't use DispatchQueue in an ephemeral View struct. You can simply change the `onAppear` to `.task` with an `await Task.sleep` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to apply a `zIndex` to `RedView`, perhaps because it is no longer treated as the top layer when being removed:

```swift
if redVisible {
    RedView($redVisible)
        .zIndex(1) // <- HERE
}
```

Alternatively, you can show `RedView` as an overlay over the blue color, then the `zIndex` is not needed (nor is the `ZStack`).

What you then see is that `RedView` seems to linger on its way out. I guess this is due to ignoring safe areas - colors like to stick to safe areas. If you move the padding from the outer `ZStack` to the individual color views inside the `ZStack` then the red view no longer lingers.

As for the direction of movement, I usually find it's best just to try it instead of trying to interpret the documentation. See also [Has the behavior of asymmetric transitions changed in SwiftUI 4 / iOS 16?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73746415/20386264).

Putting it all together, I think this works the way you were wanting it to:

```swift
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.blue.padding()

        if redVisible {
            RedView($redVisible)
                .padding()
                .zIndex(1)
                .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
        }
    }
    .onAppear{
        // as before
    }
}
```

...and also comment out `.customTransitions()` inside `RedView`.

[image: Animation]

Comment: BRILLIANT! Thanks!